# Spring - problem with task scheduler

Tags: java, spring, configuration, scheduled-tasks

I have a strange problem with task scheduler. Here are three tested configurations of `pingProducer` in my `appliacationContext.xml`. The first and the second work. The third, which should produce the ping every hour, doesn't - it produces the ping every minute. Am I missing something?

```
<!-- Ping scheduler - WORKS - every second -->
<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="pingProducer" method="producePingRequest" cron="* * * * * ?" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<!-- Ping scheduler - WORKS - every minute -->
<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="pingProducer" method="producePingRequest" cron="0 * * * * ?" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<!-- Ping scheduler - DOES NOT WORK - every minute -->
<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="pingProducer" method="producePingRequest" cron="0 0 * * * ?" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to:

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="pingProducer" method="producePingRequest" cron="50 0 * * * ?" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

EDIT: once per hour, on the 50th second

Comment: Why do I have to run it on the 50th second and not immediately?

Comment: But it still does not work. This worked for me: `cron="30 0 0/1 * * ?"` and I don't know why

Comment: cron="30 0 0/1 * * ?" works because 0/x means run after every x hour from 0 o'clock.

Answer (score 0):

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
<task:scheduled ref="pingProducer" method="producePingRequest" cron="0 0 0/1 * * ?" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

cron="0 0 0/1 * * ?" works because 0/x means run after every x hour from 0 o'clock.